# How can i extract the maximum number in graph python?

Tags: python

I made a graph with python?

```
x = []
y = []
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

how can I extract the maximum point like this picture:

[image: this is my graph and the maximum points I need]

I want to extract the firs and last and defined point from y list to a new list

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html sounds like the tool you need.

Comment: in this tool x is equal to x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]. but I want to give it my x and y. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
ymax = max(y)
xpos = y.index(ymax)
xmax = x[xpos]
```

Comment: OP's image highlights multiple peak points, not a single maximum.

Comment: @AKX  .yes I need them

Answer (score 0):

I obviously didn't have your dataset at hand, so I had to "freehand" something similar (generated by the `generate_data()` function).

```
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks


def generate_data(length):
    points = []
    for x in range(length):
        i = x / length
        p = 0
        p -= abs(i - .1)
        p += abs(i - .3) * 1.6
        p -= abs(i - .5) * 1.4
        p += abs(i - .6) * 2.7
        p -= abs(i - .7) * 3
        points.append(p + random.uniform(0, .02))
    # Normalize data to 0..1
    points = np.array(points)
    points -= points.min()
    points /= points.max()

    return points


data = generate_data(500)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(data, distance=15, prominence=.05)
plt.plot(data)
plt.vlines(peaks, 0, 1)
plt.show()
```

This plots something like this – you will need to tweak the `distance` and `prominence` values to fit your purposes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my friend. Can you tell me how to extract X and Y of these points into a separate list? like this: x=  [10,12,18], y = [0.2, 0.4, 0.8], and how can I inter my list to this algorithm?

Comment: You can use the [`interp1d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) function to turn your x/y lists into a "regular" function, then use that function to generate a single list of `y` points you can use this approach on.